# Excel converting table into rows

Tags: excel

I have a table in excel:

[image]

I want to write an equation that would populate the value column based on department, month and year of the above table

[image]

Any suggestions for the equation?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I tried a three match  index function. But it seems that the equation errors out if the months are same and years are different. equation: =INDEX($L$5:$T$7,MATCH(K15,$K$5:$K$7,0),MATCH(L15,$L$4:$T$4,0),MATCH(M15,$L$3:$T$3,0))

Comment: do the power query version, it is much easier and more responsive.